# Protractor with Cucumber - scenario not getting invoked

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

We are new to using Protractor, have followed the below link to try the test setup.
http://maushamgupta.blogspot.com/2016/09/getting-started-with-protractor-cucumber.html

Below is the conf file (named as protractor.conf.js).

```
var config;
config = {

    //chromeDriver:'path\\to\\your\\chromedriver.exe',
    //seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=path\\to\\your\\IEDriverServer.exe'], //incase you want to test your application on internet explorer
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

    specs: 'testwithpro.feature',

    capabilities: {
          browserName: 'chrome'
       },

    framework: 'custom', // need to add for protractor 3.x and above
    frameworkPath: './node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework',  // need to add for protractor 
    output:'./output.json',                                                                          //3.x and above

    cucumberOpts: {
          // define your step definitions in this file
          require: ['./testwithpro.js'],
          //format: './node_modules/pretty',
          tags:'false'
       }
};

exports.config = config;
```

### testwithpro.feature

Feature: Testing Application

Scenario: Testing Login
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter username
    And I enter password
    And I click on login button
    Then I should see Homepage

### testwithpro.js

```
var myStepDefinitionsWrapper = function () {

this.Given(/^I am on the login page$/, function (callback) {

  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

  console.log('testing');
  browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; // To be added if the application is non-angular
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize(); // To maximize the window
  //browser.get("https://www.facebook.com").then(function(){
  //  callback(); // To tell the cucumber that we are done with this step
  //})

            browser.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        browser.wait(function () {
        browser.sleep(10000);
        callback(); // To tell the cucumber that we are done with this step
        }, 20 * 10000);



});

this.When(/^I enter username$/, function (callback) {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
element(by.id("email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com").then(function(){
  callback();
 });
});

this.When(/^I enter password$/, function (callback) {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  element(by.id("pass")).sendKeys("*****").then(function(){
  callback();
 });
});

this.When(/^I click on login button$/, function (callback) {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions 
  element(by.id("u_0_l")).click().then(function(){
  callback();
 });
});

};
module.exports = myStepDefinitionsWrapper;
```

### package.json (protractor-cucumber-framework)

```
"chai": "^4.1.2",
"chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
"chai-like": "^0.2.14",
"eslint": "^5.4.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^3.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-mocha": "^5.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.2",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"httpster": "^1.0.4",
"mocha": "^5.2.0",
"multidep": "2.0.2",
"prettier": "^1.14.2",
"protractor": "^5.4.0"
```

### package.json (protractor)

"dependencies": {
    "@types/q": "^0.0.32",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.0",
    "blocking-proxy": "^1.0.0",
    "browserstack": "^1.5.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "glob": "^7.0.3",
    "jasmine": "2.8.0",
    "jasminewd2": "^2.1.0",
    "optimist": "~0.6.0",
    "q": "1.4.1",
    "saucelabs": "^1.5.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "3.6.0",
    "source-map-support": "~0.4.0",
    "webdriver-js-extender": "2.1.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.6"
  },
  "deprecated": false,
  "description": "Webdriver E2E test wrapper for Angular.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chalk": "^0.4.28",
    "@types/glob": "^5.0.29",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/minimatch": "^2.0.28",
    "@types/minimist": "^1.1.28",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/optimist": "^0.0.29",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "chai": "~3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "~5.3.0",
    "clang-format": "1.0.49",
    "expect.js": "~0.3.1",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clang-format": "1.0.23",
    "gulp-tslint": "^7.0.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2",
    "lodash": "^4.5.1",
    "marked": "^0.3.3",
    "mocha": "2.5.3",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.3",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "tslint": "^4.1.1",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "vrsource-tslint-rules": "^4.0.1"
  },

### package.json (cucumber)

"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.3",
    "assertion-error-formatter": "^2.0.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
    "cli-table3": "^0.5.1",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "cross-spawn": "^6.0.5",
    "cucumber-expressions": "^6.0.0",
    "cucumber-tag-expressions": "^1.1.1",
    "duration": "^0.2.1",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
    "figures": "2.0.0",
    "gherkin": "^5.0.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.3",
    "indent-string": "^3.1.0",
    "is-generator": "^1.0.2",
    "is-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "knuth-shuffle-seeded": "^1.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mz": "^2.4.0",
    "progress": "^2.0.0",
    "resolve": "^1.3.3",
    "serialize-error": "^3.0.0",
    "stack-chain": "^2.0.0",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
    "string-argv": "0.1.1",
    "title-case": "^2.1.1",
    "util-arity": "^1.0.2",
    "verror": "^1.9.0"
  },
  "deprecated": false,
  "description": "The official JavaScript implementation of Cucumber.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "ansi-html": "^0.0.7",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.1.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "16.2.2",
    "chai": "^4.0.1",
    "coffee-script": "^1.10.0",
    "connect": "^3.4.0",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.0",
    "dependency-lint": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.10.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^6.0.1",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "mustache": "^2.3.0",
    "nyc": "^12.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.5.2",
    "serve-static": "^1.10.0",
    "sinon": "^6.0.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.2.0",
    "stream-to-string": "^1.1.0",
    "tmp": "^0.0.33"
  },

When we run the cmd "protractor protractor.conf.js", the output shown in terminal is this -

[23:02:58] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[23:02:58] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub

0 scenarios
0 steps
0m00.000s
[23:03:02] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[23:03:02] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

It does not process the scenario in the feature file and does not launch the web page defined in the test definition js file. The strange part is that the same output is shown even if we change the specs file name to "1testwithpro.feature" (such that it does not exist). No error is thrown.

Please let us know what we might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

Comment: `specs` expects an Array. Try `specs: ['testwithpro.feature'],`

Comment: I tried this, still the same result - 0 scenarios, 0 steps

Comment: Can you show your project folder structure which can illustrate the relative path of `protractor.conf.js` and `testwithpro.feature`

Comment: All the 3 files are in the same folder - protractor.conf.js, testwithpro.feature and testwithpro.js

Comment: Please show your `package.json` and `testwithpro.feature`

Comment: I have updated the feature and test definition files. Do not have a package.json.

Comment: One possibility is your protractor, cucumberjs and protractor-cucumber-framework are not compatible, they can't work well together. That's why I ask `package.json`.  So you can check the version of them from `node_modules\<package>\package.json`, then I can try on my box.

Comment: Understood. I have listed the dependencies from package.json for all the 3. Please check.

Comment: I want the version of them, not the dependencies of them. You should check the `"_id": ` or `"version: "` filed in `package.json` of them to get the version.

Answer (score 0):

Change `specs: 'testwithpro.feature'` to `specs: ['./testwithpro.feature']`

Remove the `tags` in the `cucumberOpts` object.

```
    cucumberOpts: {
      require: ['./testwithpro.js']
   },
   specs: ['./testwithpro.feature']
```